# Why getting unwanted NIL after right answer is returned in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am writing a lisp program called `pellnumbers` to return a list of pell numbers. However, I always get `NIL` right after a test result. I am new to Lisp and do not understand much about its errors. Could you please help me out? Thank you!
Below is my code

```
;define a function of how to compute a pell number
(defun P (n)
    (cond 
        ((= n 0) 0)
        ((= n 1) 1)
        (t (+ (* 2 (P (- n 1))) (P (- n 2))))))

;define an iterative function to return a sequence of pell numbers
(defun pellnumbers (n)
    (prog
        (setq res '())
        (loop for i from 0 to n
              do (setq res (append res (list (P i))))
        )
        (print res)))

;test cases
(print (pellnumbers 0))
(print (pellnumbers 6))
(print (pellnumbers 9))
```

and here is the result I get

```
(0) 
NIL 
(0 1 2 5 12 29 70) 
NIL 
(0 1 2 5 12 29 70 169 408 985) 
NIL
```

Comment: Use backticks \` to format code, not `'`. Also check the preview before posting...

Comment: did not know that. I just edited. Thank you

Comment: You can see that there are more than just three `print` statements in the code.

Comment: you meant the test cases?

Comment: any bug report should include a reproducible test case: what is the Lisp you are using and how are you running your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the last form evaluated is the return value. `print` returns `NIL`, and being the last form in the `prog`, `prog` returns `NIL`, which becomes the return value for `pellnumbers`.

Whether you use `prog`, `progn` or `let` is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 4):

`NIL` is not an error. It's just a a piece of data, which is both a symbol and means the empty list.

a few hints for your code:

**it's unclear why you use `PROG` but you need to check it's syntax**

The syntax of PROG:

```
prog
    ({var | (var [init-form])}*)
  declaration*
  {tag | statement}*
```

Your code lacks a list of variables. The form `(setq res '())` is wrong.

Why not just use LET instead.

**you need to indent your code properly**

Example indent:

```
(defun pellnumbers (n)
  (prog
      (setq res '())
    (loop for i from 0 to n
          do (setq res (append res (list (P i)))))
  (print res)))
```

This makes it easier to spot syntax errors. Again: your usage of PROG is a) **wrong** and b) not needed.

**your code prints twice**

There is a `print` statement inside the function `pellnumbers` and your *testcases* also have a print statement.

That's why two values are being printed. The result of `pellnumbers` is always `NIL`, so always `NIL` is printed, for any testcase in your code.

Comment: thank you for your comment! I made a typo here. It should be ```progn```, not ```prog```. I also removed ```print``` function on the test cases, and it works fine now

Comment: @Tom: if you use PROGN, then you don't need it at all. A DEFUN provides already a sequence of instructions - in the syntax it is called a *body*. But you need to declare the RES variable (using LET or &AUX in the arg list or similar).

Comment: @Tom Constructs like `defun`, `lambda`, `let` and numerous others have an "implicit progn": zero or more forms can be enclosed in them. If one or more forms are present, they are evaluated in order, and the value of the last one is the overall result value.